# How do I edit '/etc/ld.so.conf' in a yocto recipe?

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, ld, bitbake, yocto-recipe

I have a yocto recipe in which I copy/install some stuff to an image. After that, I want to add a line to the `/etc/ld.so.conf` file like this, so that the dynamic loader finds my library files:

```
do_install(){
  # install some stuff...

  echo /opt/myStuff/lib >> /etc/ld.so.conf
  ldconfig
}
```

During the build process I get the following error which aborts the build process:

```
...
| DEBUG: Python function extend_recipe_sysroot finished
| DEBUG: Executing shell function do_install
| /home/debian/Devel/myYocto/build/tmp/work/myTarget/myRecipe/1.0-r0/temp/run.do_install.3176: 203: cannot create /etc/ld.so.conf: Permission denied
| WARNING: exit code 2 from a shell command.
ERROR: Task (/home/debian/Devel/myYocto/poky/meta-myLayer/myRecipe/myRecipe.bb:do_install) failed with exit code '1'
```

Now to my question: How do I add a custom path to the dynamic loader by adding a line or editing the `/etc/ld.so.conf` file in a yocto recipe?

Comment: I'm not voting to close, because StackOverflow is more active than Unix/Linux SE so you might get more eyes here, but also you might have luck asking over on [on that StackExchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Is it okay to copy the question there?

Comment: According to [Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu), not really, though you can have the question [migrated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work). In practice, if you link back to this version of the question so it's clear that you're not spamming, I personally have never seen it be an issue to leave the original one up and also ask on a different StackExchange site. I'm not a moderator, though, so not an authority.

Comment: Thanks for you comment. Lets see what happens with [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/746814/how-do-i-edit-etc-ld-so-conf-in-a-yocto-recipe) :)

Comment: Could you please elaborate, why you see a need to manipulate the system global linker search paths? Is there any specific reason, why can't you use properly set `rpath`s in your project and make every binary fully relocatable (i.e. work from any place inside the file system hierarchy, given it's not mounted `noexec`)?